# How to "group by" in django serializers for same model

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django-Python and learning to build serializers. I understand the basic implementation of Serializers but stuck with this following particular requirement.

This is my Customer Events model -

```
class CustomerEvents(models.Model):
       account_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
       event_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
```

Sample records in CustomerEvents:

```
Account Number    Event Type
A12345             Billing Issues
A12345             Video Services
A12345             Sales
```

I want to create a CustomerEventsSerializer which will return values as below:

```
{ 
  "account_number" : A12345, 
  "event_types"    : ['Billing Issues', 'Video Services', 'Sales']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dummy serializer for it.

```
CustomerEventsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    def to_representation:(self,obj):  
        rep= super(CustomerEventsSerializer,self).to_representation(obj)  
        rep['events']= [ customer.event for customer in CustomerEvents.objects.filter(account_number=obj.account_number)]  
        return rep  
    class Meta:  
        model = CustomerEvents  
        fields = ('account_number',)
```

Comment: I have tried above solution using same serialize and mode, but I got response like this [
    {
        "account_number": "A12345             ",
        "event_type": "c"
    },
    {
        "account_number": "A12345             ",
        "event_type": "b"
    },
    {
        "account_number": "A12345             ",
        "event_type": "a"
    }
]

Here is my model view set
class CustomerEventsSerializerViewSet(generics.BulkModelViewSet):
 queryset = CustomerEvents.objects.all()
 serializer_class = CustomerEventsSerializer
please let me know where I am making mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by
which allows you to group by and return queryset.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.general import ArrayAgg

qs = CustomerEvents.objects.group_by('account_number').annotate(
        event_types=ArrayAgg('event_type')))
```

Now you can create `CustomerEventsSerializer` with `account_number` and `event_types` method to handle the list for `qs[0].event_types`.

```
class CustomerEventsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event_types = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerEvents
        fields = ('account_numer', 'event_types')
```